# Async API Call Looop

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, api, asynchronous

I have written a script that assembles a list of URL's for which I need to loop through each URL to send as an API call.

```html
const fs = require('fs');
const JSZip = require('jszip');
const directoryFile = fs.readdirSync('./zipped');
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
var accessToken = "Bearer <ACCESS TOKEN>";
var url = 'https://<API URL>/';
var data = JSON.stringify({"status":"CONFIGURED", "payloadTracingEnabledFlag":true});
var headers2 = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-HTTP-Method-Override': 'PATCH',
    'Authorization': accessToken
};

const dir = ('./zipped/');

function buildApiUrls () {
    new Promise((data, err) => {
        fs.readFile((dir + directoryFile), function (err, data) {
            JSZip.loadAsync(data).then(function (zip) {
                const files = Object.keys(zip.files);
                //console.log(files);
                if (err) throw err;
                //console.log(files);
                return files
            })
                .then(value => {
                    const newFileArr = [];
                    value.forEach((files) => {
                        const pkgName = files.substring(files.indexOf("_", files.indexOf("_")) + 1, files.lastIndexOf("_"));
                        const fileExt = files.split('.').pop();
                        const pkgExtract = (pkgName + "." + fileExt);
                        //console.log(pkgExtract);
                        if (pkgExtract !== 'package.properties') {
                            //const pkgExtract = (pkgName + "." + fileExt);
                            //console.log(pkgExtract);
                            const split_string = pkgExtract.split(/(\w[0-9]\.)/);
                            const versionSlice = split_string.slice(0 - 6).join('');
                            versionSlice.slice(0, -4).toString();
                            const nameSlice = split_string[0].toString();
                            const name = nameSlice.slice(0, -1);
                            const apiDeployable = name + "|" + versionSlice;
                            //console.log(apiDeployable);
                            //data = ("APIDEPLOYABALE = ") + encodeURIComponent(apiDeployable);
                            //newFileArr.push(url + apiDeployable);
                            const apiUrls = (url + apiDeployable);
                            //console.log(apiUrls);
                            return apiUrls;
                        }

                    });
                });
        });

    })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
}


function postApi (apiUrls) {
    const promises = async apiUrlCall => {
        return await fetch(url, {method: "POST", headers: headers2, body: data})
    };

   return promises(apiUrls);

}

postApi(buildApiUrls()).then(resp => {
    const response = resp.json();
    console.log(response)
});
```

Presently, function "buildApiUrls()" returns correct output and the 4 URL's correctly display in a console.log.  The issue is towards then where I am trying to loop through the list of 4 URL's and send each as an individual API Call.  My output is the following:

[image]

I know my issue is with the "postAPI()" and how I am calling the two functions together.

I am positive the API Call works because individually I can use any of the output URL's and send a call successfully.  How can I get this call working so it loops through each of the 4 output URL's and provides the response for each call?  I have tried outputting the URL's into an array and successfully get an array of URL's that I can loop through but i have not had any`enter code here` success with that either.  All help is appreciated.

Comment: Already answered much of this question once here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60778064/816620, but you seemed to have ignored my answer.  Your current code is full of all sorts of problems, even though several of us showed you better ways in your last question.  I could list a dozen problems with this code, all of which are solved in my previous answer.  I started writing an answer to this question when I realized, "wait I've already written this before".  Please attempt to actually learn from the answers people give you before you charge ahead with the same flawed code in another question.

Comment: Problems: Mixing of plain callbacks with promises.  Not calling `resolve()` for your manually created promise therefore it never resolves and never has a resolved value.  No error handling for your manually created promise (lots of places you're not calling `reject(err)`.  And so on....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute .Then() promise NodeJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60775523/execute-then-promise-nodejs)

Comment: Yes....I used suggestions made by jfriend.  Took me most of yesterday and all weekend to get it, but I finally see what everyone was saying about not resolving any data.  Lastly, I was combing Callbacks with Promises (this was mainly due to trying numerous examples online) in an attempt to get something to work.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was based off jfriends comments on a previous post and the flow looks something like:

```html
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
          <code to do something>
            return output1
        }).then
            <code to do something>
            return output2
        }).then
            <code to do something>
            return output3
            }).then( fetchLoop = async () => {
                const resArr = [];
                for() {
                    const response = await fetch(element, {method: "POST", headers: headers, body: data});
                    const res = await response;
                    resArr.push(res);
                    console.log(resArr);
                }
            })
        })
});
```

My issues stemmed from numerous things, but first and foremost a lack of understanding async operations within JS/Nodejs (especially when needing to make several async API calls within the same script).  Apologies for frustrating some of you, the assistance is appreciated as I am learning this stuff as I go.....